# DBeaver 5.3.2 reconnect after db change (CREATE TABLE call)

Tags: postgresql, dbeaver

SQL scripts work on the active object in DBeaver. If you add a new table to your active database via an SQL statement in a script, DBeaver does not automatically update the navigator entries. Even when chosing to reconnnect to the database, the navigator stays not updated. To see the changes, the user has to disconnect and then connect to the database server again. Additionally, the active database changes in my case everytime I connect to it. I use postgresql with two databases: one custom database I change with scripts and the "postgres" database, which always becomes the active object by default.

Do you have the same obstacles, when creating new tables, or is there a way to work without the need to close and start the database connection?

Is there a way to attach a script to a special database without having to set one database to be the active one by hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you notice the "Refresh" button, usually at the bottom right of DBeaver screen?

[image: bottom-right menu]

Also accessible with F5 or from right-click menus from the database navigator:

[image: from database navigator]

Comment: When the database is highlighted, F5 or a refresh works just fine - thanks.